# How can I mock/spy on a useContext hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jestjs, react-context

I am attempting to unit test two exported helper functions that both call `useContext` on my default context value. However, I can't seem to get it working after a lot of looking online.

```
export const func1 = () => {
    const { key1, key2 } = useContext(MyContext);
    return { key1, key2 };
}

export const func2 = () => {
    const { key2 } = useContext(MyContext);

    // some more complex stuff here
}
```

Test

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

...

it('with mock', () => {
    jest.mock('react', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react'),
      useContext: (ctx: any) => mockUseContext(ctx)
    }));

    useContext.mockImplementation(ctx => ({ someKey: 'someVal' }));

    // Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type ' (context: Context ) => T

    expect(func1()).toBe({ someKey: 'someVal' });
});

it('with spyOn', () => {
     jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext').mockImplementation(() => ({ someKey: 'someVal' }));

     expect(func1()).toBe({ someKey: 'someVal' });
});
```

Comment: _Don't_ mock `useContext`, or any other part of React's API (which you don't own). Test _behaviour_, not implementation - when the hook is rendered _in `MyContext`_, does it return the right value? See e.g. https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how would one approach testing my `func1` function that simply uses the `useContext` and returns some of it's values?

Answer (score -3):

When unit testing helper functions that use the `useContext` hook, you need to mock the `useContext` function to provide your own mock values. Here's how you can do it:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useContext: jest.fn(),
}));

const mockContextValue = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
};

describe('Helper Functions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    useContext.mockReturnValue(mockContextValue);
  });

  it('should return the correct values from func1', () => {
    const { func1 } = require('./yourHelperFunctionsFile');
    const result = func1();
    expect(result).toEqual(mockContextValue);
  });

  it('should work with func2', () => {
    const { func2 } = require('./yourHelperFunctionsFile');
    // Test func2 here
  });
});
```

In this example, we use `jest.mock` to mock the `useContext` function from React. Then, we set the return value of the `useContext` mock to `mockContextValue`, which is an object representing the values you want to use in your tests.

Inside each test, we import the specific function being tested and call it. In the case of `func1`, we expect the result to be equal to `mockContextValue`.

Note that in order to make the mocking work correctly, you need to make sure you import the functions inside each test case, as shown in the example. This ensures that the mocked version of `useContext` is used when calling the function.

Feel free to modify the code as per your needs and add additional assertions and test cases for `func2` or any other helper functions you want to test.

Comment: Hmm... This doesn't seem to work for me. This looks like things I'd seen online, but the line where you have `useContext.mockReturnValue...` referring to the imported `{ useContext }`, it flags up for me `Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type ' (context: Context ) => T'`

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW Looks like [link profile ChatGPT spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389978/902710)

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).